# searching text in a file remotely

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, ftp

I have log files, based on Linux servers, and I'm working on Windows OS.
I'm using Filezilla to log in the Linux server and searching specific text or strings by open the log file.
I want to automate this process using batch in Windows, I tried using below;

```
@echo off
cls
set /p string="Enter the string: "
echo open xx.xx.xx.xx 21> ftpc.dat
echo xxxxxxxx>> ftpc.dat
echo xxxxxxxx>> ftpc.dat
echo bin >> ftpc.dat
echo grep '%string%' /PATH IS HERE/log.log >> ftpc.dat
ftp -s:ftpc.dat
```

I'm just new to that, I want ideas on that, how  I automate this search process? where I can make a search tool for any text, that this tool goes and find specific file in linux server and shows the results in lines (before/after 15 lines) of thatsearch results.
Do I need to write bash scripts, or I can do this basic script in batch file as above to show or output the results?

Comment: Is it okay for you to install [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on your Windows computer?

Comment: @wallyk, then it will be off-topic as it will request off-site resource!

Comment: Good to keep the rules in mind, but, ultimately, expeditiously finding a useful solution is the more important consideration.

Comment: I think this **is** off-topic and should be closed...

Comment: Hi @wallyk     I dont want to solve this using putty, I know with putty, can grep that easily, I need a search utility, and need to script that. ITs not only one file, its many file, but I need the script for one file then apply to other files, and other servers ..

Comment: If the search results return less than the whole set of files, it is more efficient to perform the `grep` on the Linux side and aggregating the results there thereby returning the result in one network connection.  That can be done with `ssh`:  Fewer connections, less network i/o.  What you seem to have in mind will work, but by transferring all the data and filtering it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of Linux servers to watch, it might be worth installing something like rsyslog or logstash. It's a big topic, but those might be good starting points in your research.

Other things to google: elasticsearch, kibana ... and their alternatives.

Comment: Hi ! Actually I have 7 remote servers, all linux based. my laptop is windows based, its restricted to install any software, I can only reach those linux servers using Filezilla or Putty, and there are couple of logs that I need them during my job for analyzing, I can use grep command to search for a text in some files, I was able to use mputty as its standalone tool without installing it. but still I need to have a search utlity that can search to a(text) within multiple servers. because sometimes I need to search for texts located in couple of last dated logs and shows 15 lines before/after

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `grep` using FTP.

So either:

- Use FTP to download whole file and grep/search it locally.
- Or (as you seem to have an SSH access too) use a command-line SSH client to execute `grep` on the server. On Windows, you can use [Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (which comes with PuTTY):

  ```
  plink -pw password user@example.com grep '%string%' /remote/path/log.log >
  ```